# SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables in my database (`wallets` and `transactions`) in my `laravel` project.

I update the `wallets` table when any records was inserted to `transactions` table.

I got this error when there is too many attempts to insert `transactions` table

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: Are you using events? Deadlock is a term related with jobs, are you using queues? Try to post more of your code.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't  understand you. I am using laravel eloquent

Comment: Post the code giving you problems so we can help you

Comment: There is no need to code. it is simply insert and update query with `laravel's eloquent`

Comment: Well, you have clearly done something different, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Yes it works...! But i got this error when i have too many requests on inserting to `transactions` table.

Comment: Okey whats your queue driver and how many workers do you have?

Comment: I don't use queue for this process

Comment: You don't spawn any jobs at all? It's weird, this issue is known to be related with using the database drive with multiple workers, are you sure, no queued events, mails, anything?

Comment: i created a queue manually for email and other stuff but i don't use queue for this problem

Comment: Check if you have jobs pending, that might be the cause, if you are using the db driver check the jobs table

Comment: Cause of this problem is multiple transactions occurs at same time so each of them locks `wallets` table.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but **you cannot have multiple transactions at the same time in a synchronous environment**

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152040/discussion-between-543310-and-asur).